# How to install Compiz effects on Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, compiz, customization

I want to install Compiz desktop effects/graphics in my GNOME 3 desktop. And I want to customise the animations being shown on my desktop. Is it possible?

Comment: You do not use compiz with gnome-shell, it has it's own composite manager.

Comment: @xangua Then, What is GNOME's own composite  manager? Is it fully customizable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, mutter (the GNOME compositor) is not customizable at all. Why they thought this was a good idea is anyone's guess, as I find the typical compositor functionality as expressed in Compiz and KDE's compositor very useful, especially the desktop cube.